# What part of speech or lesson to learn how to write verbs end in -ing?

Tags: grammaire

I want to write the sentence:
"Some activities I do well are: running, reading, swimming, etc..."

Unless there are some rules or exceptions I am unaware about, I am pretty sure I know how to write everything before the colon.

Certaines activités que je fais bien sont:

However, I can't find a lesson on the end part of the sentence. I want to know more than just what the answer is, but why is it that answer. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Usually these are translated using a noun:
*Certaines activités que je fais bien sont: la course, la lecture, la nage, etc.*
One can also use the corresponding verbs:
*Ce que je fais bien: courir, lire, nager, etc."*